# Connexion Flask logging formatting

Tags: python, flask, python-logging, connexion

I am struggling in setting the logging for a connexion flask rest api, with a gevent server. I would like to log only the message after each  request like `GET /health HTTP/1.1` or even better just the http status code, e.g. `200`. I follow the flask docu and  set up a `dictConfig` before creating the app. Like this:

```
import connexion
from logging.config import dictConfig


def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__)
    app.app.logger.info('This is a check!')
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
    app.run(server='gevent')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {'default': {
            'format': 'Custom message: %(message)s',
        }},
        'handlers': {'wsgi': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
            'formatter': 'default'
        }},
        'root': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['wsgi']
        }
    })

    main()
```

Starting the app and after sending two requests (one 200 and one 405):

```
Custom message: This is a check!
127.0.0.1 - - [2021-03-15 12:42:35] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 126 0.001714
127.0.0.1 - - [2021-03-15 12:42:35] "PUT /health HTTP/1.1" 405 275 0.000711
```

So, before the `app.run()` the `app.app.logging()` looks fine and send just the message `Custom message: This is a check!`, but after that the logs do not follow the dictionary anymore.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the dictConfig is not being used since you are not assigning it to anything.

You would need something like

```
logging.config.dictConfig(yourconfig)
```

where yourconfig is your dictConfig. Move your dictConfig to main() to have it in the same scope, or import it from a file if you choose to keep it separate.

See: [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected if the `server` is not `gevent`, so just using `app.run()`. Unfortunately, it doesn't  if `gevent` is used.

Comment: Any idea how to log just the 200 status code? I did not expect that using `%(message)` I get `127.0.0.1 - - [2021-03-15 12:42:35] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 126 0.001714`. This is I think the standard  `werkzeug` logs, I do not get how to change it